# In Oracle I want to insert data into a table in a db service from another db service without a database link.Both db services on the same db instance

Tags: oracle

In Oracle I want to insert data into a table in a db service from another db service without using database link.Both db services are on the same database instance.

```
insert into dm2m.iotCharge@BFDOCUMENTDATA(documentId, name, descr, quantity, balance_amount, total_amount) 
    select documentID, tariff, Description, quantity, amount, total_amount
    from dm2m.fn_getIotCharges_pkg.fn_getIotCharges(100);
```

In the above query `dm2m.iotCharge` table is in the `BF_DocumentData` database service. And the the package `dm2m.fn_getIotCharges_pkg.fn_getIotCharges(100)` is on `XMLDB` database service. Both database services are on the same db instance.
We have a user named `dm2m` in both of the database services.

package and package body definition is as below,

```
create or replace PACKAGE dm2m.fn_getIotCharges_pkg
AS
   TYPE tt_fn_getIotCharges_type IS TABLE OF tt_fn_getIotCharges%ROWTYPE;
   FUNCTION fn_getIotCharges(v_documentID IN NUMBER) RETURN tt_fn_getIotCharges_type PIPELINED;
END;

create or replace PACKAGE BODY dm2m.fn_getIotCharges_pkg AS
    
      FUNCTION fn_getIotCharges(v_documentId IN NUMBER) RETURN tt_fn_getIotCharges_type PIPELINED
          AS
                v_temp   SYS_REFCURSOR;
                v_temp_1 tt_fn_getIotCharges%rowtype;
            BEGIN
              OPEN v_temp FOR
                SELECT v_documentId documentID, EVB.PROFILE_NAME AS Tariff,EVB.NAME AS Description,EVB.QUANTITY, EVB.AMOUNT, 
                    ET.AMOUNT AS TOTAL_AMOUNT FROM 
                    dm2m.AR_ITEMS_EVENTS_VFQ_BALANCE EVB
                    INNER JOIN 
                    dm2m.AR_ITEMS_EVENTS_TOTAL ET ON ET.EVENTS_ID = EVB.EVENTS_ID;

            LOOP
                FETCH v_temp INTO v_temp_1;
                EXIT WHEN v_temp%notfound;
                PIPE ROW ( v_temp_1 );
            END LOOP;

            RETURN;
      END fn_getIotCharges;

    END fn_getIotCharges_pkg;
```

The table (tt_fn_getIotCharges) has the below columns,
[image]

When I ran the above insert query , I get the below error.

> ORA-22804: remote operations not permitted on object tables or
> user-defined type columns

I have some questions here,

1. Why the above insert query is throwing error here.?
2. How can I achieve this without using database link?
3. Using database link causes any performance issues?

Comment: Define what you mean by "database": do you mean *schema* (i.e. user, in Oracle) in the same database *instance*, or two separate database *instances* (different SID, server processes, etc.)?

Comment: Yes database means a schema or user. And we have one database instance and different service name. Let me edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error ORA-22804 is specifically over the use of that function, which is returning a custom datatype. You cannot use that datatype to send data over a database link to an instance where that datatype isn't defined.

Regardless, the use of the pipeline function is at the root of your problem.

Instead, why not use a normal view:

```
create or replace view v_getIotCharges
as
SELECT EVB.PROFILE_NAME AS Tariff,
       EVB.NAME AS Description, 
       EVB.QUANTITY, 
       EVB.AMOUNT, 
       ET.AMOUNT AS TOTAL_AMOUNT 
  FROM dm2m.AR_ITEMS_EVENTS_VFQ_BALANCE EVB
 INNER JOIN dm2m.AR_ITEMS_EVENTS_TOTAL ET 
    ON ET.EVENTS_ID = EVB.EVENTS_ID;
```

Then use the same insert:

```
insert into dm2m.iotCharge@BFDOCUMENTDATA 
       (documentId, name, descr, quantity, balance_amount, total_amount) 
select 100, tariff, Description, quantity, amount, total_amount
  from dm2m.v_getIotCharges;
```

If *not* using a database link (i.e. inserting data to different schema in the same instance), just grant insert privileges on the destination table to the user performing the insert:

```
grant insert on target_schema_name.bfdocumentdata to source_schema_name;
```

Then use the same insert:

```
insert into target_schema_name.iotCharge 
       (documentId, name, descr, quantity, balance_amount, total_amount) 
select 100, tariff, Description, quantity, amount, total_amount
  from dm2m.v_getIotCharges;
```

Comment: If we convert `functions` to `view` then `view` takes more space ( table space or so) compared to `function` ?. We have 300+ `functions` to convert to `view`.

Comment: views take almost **no** space. they are simply stored queries. strictly speaking they will take less space than your functions to store in the data dictionary.